# Ending a Raspberry Pi Slideshow with fbi

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer, fbi

I've made a digital picture frame using Raspbian booting to the command line interface. I invoke a slideshow with the following command after logging in with SSH with my mac:

`ssh pi@<IPaddress>`

`sudo fbi -a -t 5 -T 2 /home/pi/Pictures/\*.* &`

That works great. But how do I stop the slideshow and return the Pi to the command prompt? Currently, if I do sudo pkill fbi, the screen on the frame freezes on the last-showed picture :). My terminal on the mac returns to the command line

Sorry for the nooby question :) I'm having the same problem after running omxplayer--I don't know how to manage these commands after they are started :)

The clear command should work, but I can't figure out how to get the clear command to execute on the raspberry pi console (it executes on the ssh terminal I'm using to remotely control the pi)

Comment: Welcome, I think fbi was really designed as a command line hence the esc/q option from the keyboard to exit :). You could try the kill followed by the bash command `clear` to remove the last image.  Only other way I can think is run fbi and pipe a key press to it something like `echo 'q' > /proc/20809/fd/0` where 20809 is the PID of fbi (note untested)

Comment: Why are you putting the process in the background? The only way to kill a background process is kill which requires the PID

Comment: I'm putting them in the background because this project is a bit more complicated. It's actually a triptych. I've written a bash script that send the fbi command to two slave consoles, and then a local one. To get the commands to execute simultaneously, I have to use &.